# Is there a data type in MySQL similar to varchar(n) that not allow numbers or special characters in it?

Tags: mysql, datatypes, varchar

Is there a data type in **MySQL** similar to `varchar(n)` that not allow numbers or special characters in it?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not that type in MySQL.